# Android In-App billing error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have followed google instructions for implementing in-app purchases service.

I was provided access to Google Play developer console as invited user. I took private key from it, and added my google account to the input field with test accounts. After that I created APK file and signed it with valid certificate. Then uploaded application to Google Play but didn't publish it. After it I created needed in-app purchases and published them. Then installed same signed apk file on my device.

Right after publishing in-app purchases and for some period of time my application was giving me message like "not found", but some time later it became available. And now I can buy all the items from the application, but no one else who installed the same APK file can't. I tried to add their email addresses into list of test accounts in profile - no luck, even the user owner of the Google Play account can't buy anything. They keep receiving something like "item you selected is not available for purchase" When they try to buy test purchase item (the one that is described in documentation) they can successfuly get "android.test.purchased: PURCHASED"

Answer (score 2):

Google Play takes a pretty long time to update its servers. When I was implementing in app billing the first time, I must have rewritten everything at least 50 times. Nothing changed, except some 12 hours later it all started working magically. Most likely their server hasn't updated yet. If you can use the test items correctly, then your implementation is likely fine, and you just need to wait for the servers to update.

Comment: we have several weeks passed - so it is not that case

Comment: How long since you created the in app item you are trying to buy?

Comment: also several weeks have passed, I can buy that item from one device and can't from another - that is the problem

Comment: Have you tried creating another item and test the app using that?

Answer (score 2):

Only the signed apk file that you uploaded in play store can be used to buy the in app product.
Did you give the in app id in the signed apk file before registering the in app id in play  store.then only others can buy the item.

as per the edit

see you have use android.test.purchase ri8 it is an test id when your make your app  real your need to replace that with  your own in-app id.Then you have a question how to obtain in-app id.its very simple after saving your app(not published) in draft there is an option to add the in app product for your app.click that option where you will see the app id in one of the field then  fill the in app id and also set corresponding amount for your product and publish the in-app product not the app.Replace the android.test.purchase with your new id in the signed apk and wait for some time so that the server can update your changes.

Comment: We have already done it, we have 3 custom in-app purchase items and their ids are used inside application, I can but them for real money from one device and can't from another one - that is the exact problem